# Linked list using typedef

Tags: c, gcc, data-structures, linked-list, typedef

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int value;
    struct node* next;
} node;

void print(node* list);

int main()
{
    node* n1;
    node* n2;
    n1 = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    n2 = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));

    n1->value = 4;
    n1->next = n2;
    n2->value = 5;
    n2->next = NULL;

    print(n1);
    return 0;
}

void print(node* list)
{
    node* p;
    p = list;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->value);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

The code works but my compiler (gcc) gives a warning that n1->next = n2 is (assignment from incompatible pointer type)
What does it mean? and how do I avoid it?

Comment: `typedef struct {` creates a struct without a tag. There is no such thing as `struct node` in your program.

Comment: `typedef struct` --> `typedef struct node`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typedef struct {...} node` declares `node` to be a type alias for a `struct` *without a tag*. In C, two otherwise identical `struct`s with different tags are not the same structure. (Furthermore, two declarations of `struct`s without tags are different `struct`s.) The declaration does not declare `struct node` at all. So `struct node* next;` refers to a different, incomplete `struct`. (It's ok that its incomplete, because you only use it as a pointer.)

Here's a a better way of doing it. (Changing `node` to `Node` is just my style; I find it easier when type names are easily distinguishable from variable names.) Note the predeclaration of the typedef, which allows its use inside the later struct definition. (It's still incomplete when its used inside the definition, but that's OK because it's a pointer.)

I also changed the `malloc` calls to use the type of the variable being defined rather than the typename, which is generally better style. (And I removed the unnecessary casts; if you plan to use C++, you should change the `malloc` to a `new` rather than adding a C-style cast.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;
};

void print(Node* list);

int main()
{
    Node* n1 = malloc(sizeof *n1);
    Node* n2 = malloc(sizeof *n2);

    n1->value = 4;
    n1->next = n2;
    n2->value = 5;
    n2->next = NULL;

    print(n1);
    return 0;
}

void print(Node* list)
{
    Node* p;
    p = list;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->value);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

(Live on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19533ccbc37f93c2))